# How to Set The Length Size of A UIButton Border Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to set the length size of a `UIButton` border. I tried using this

```
[[jb layer] setBorderLength:2.2f];
```

but got a error saying "setBorderLength is not a method".

Here's my code for my `UIButton` border:

```
[[jb layer] setBorderWidth:2.2f];
[[jb layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
```

Comment: what do you mean by border length? border depends on the size of the object. You can change the size of your button and that in turn will change your border length.

Answer (score 0):

setting a layer border parameters :

```
jb.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;


jb.layer.borderWidth = 1;


jb.layer.cornerRadius = jb.bounds.size.width * 0.1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no border length. The border width determines how thick your border is.
The border is around your frame. If you mean your border to be appear wider around your button consider changing the frame.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create layers and add it to the button to handle this scenario

```
CALayer * layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, 1.0);
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
layer.opacity = 0.1f;
[self.button.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

This will add border on only the top border of button.
Change the frame and add 3 more layers to cover left right and bottom